# What is the data type that can accept empty or have one value in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

In a XSD file I have an element that have two digit number `price="90"` but I want it also to accept empty. What is the data type to be specified in the XSD?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the element nillable.

```
<xs:element name="Price"
            nillable="true">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:totalDigits value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: But if you do that, it will only accept an empty value if the element says `xsi:nil="true"`, which is pretty clunky.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach is to define the element as having a list type:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="twoDigitNumber">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:totalDigits value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  
  <xs:simpleType name="listOfTwoDigitNumbers">
    <xs:list itemType="twoDigitNumber"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  
  <xs:simpleType name="optionalTwoDigitNumber">
    <xs:restriction base="listOfTwoDigitNumbers">
      <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Another popular approach is to define a union type with member types being (a) a two-digit integer, and (b) a string with maxLength=0. The two approaches achieve the same effect in terms of validation, but will work differently if you use data binding technologies, or schema-aware XPath expressions.

I'm not a great fan of nillable/xsi:nil. Asking people to label empty instances with `xsi:nil` when it's perfectly obvious that the element is empty seems to serve no useful purpose; and it doesn't work for attributes.

Comment: Agreed that the ```xsi:nil``` option is not the best and yours looks cleaner in the output but also complex in the schema. Unfortunately some code generators (like xsd2code) cannot work with these kind of schema's. It created an string property based on the schema. But I will keep this one in mind. The first colleague that complains about the ```xsi:nil``` will get your solution.